# how to load all user js files after @RenderBody() complete in MVC single page application

Tags: angularjs, single-page-application

When I generate a MVC5 app using AngularJs, the _Layout.cshtml has the @Scripts.Render at the end of the file after the @RenderBody(), @Scripts.Render contains some animation related script, these script should execute after @RenderBody() elements loaded. Now all scripts are included into page before @RenderBody() elements loaded completely, so my script is not applying to my DOM elements.

I'm new to MVC & AngularJs Single page application. Please help me to achieve this.

What is the correct approach?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: @RenderBody() is called on server side so it shouldn't be the reason it prevents your animation scripts. One thing I would check is the order of your scripts being loaded in browser.

Comment: Order of script loading are fine. I put debugger in my script, inside my script jQuery("#slider1") does not contain value because id #slider1 present inside @RenderBody(). First my script file loading after that only elements getting rendered.

Comment: Try this: open the page in browser, view source page, checked the id, value, and your scripts loading order there.

Comment: Ya correct, I couldn't find #slider1 in page source, but I can able to find when I do inspect element. Can you please clear me how it is possible and how to manage this?

Comment: Would be more helpful if you post some code.

Comment: Basically I'm using AngularJs in MVC application as Single page application. My header and footer inside _Layout.cshtml and body of connect is @RenderBody(). Index.cshtml contains only <div ng-view></div>. Body of the content I placed inside a html file, using angular js routing concept i'll filling ng-view.

Comment: Please some one help me on this issue...